# Java wrapper for ROOT. OutputStreamReader is blocking

Tags: java, bufferedreader, root-framework

TLDR; is there a friendly way to get Java to read from ROOT stdout? And vice versa?

I have a Java function that launches a ROOT process. Java and ROOT then communicate via stdin and stdout. Well, that's the plan anyway. For some reason I can't get any info output by `cin`(ROOT) to be accessible via the Java process.

I'm sure I've stumbled upon several simultanious gotchas here, sorry about the long question, the code included is as simple as possible

ROOT CODE:

```
void test_io(){
    while (true){
        string in_str;
        cout << "ROOT:: loop iteration";  
        //cout.flush(); flushing has no effect  
        cin >> in_str;
        cout << "ROOT:: received string " << in_str;
    }
}
```

I run this code with the following command:

```
root -b -q external/test_io.C
```

The output looks like:

```
   ------------------------------------------------------------
  | Welcome to ROOT 6.02/05                http://root.cern.ch |
  |                               (c) 1995-2014, The ROOT Team |
  | Built for linuxx8664gcc                                    |
  | From tag v6-02-05, 9 February 2015                         |
  | Try '.help', '.demo', '.license', '.credits', '.quit'/'.q' |
   ------------------------------------------------------------

root [0] 
Processing external/test_io.C...
ROOT:: loop iteration
```

When I enter some text with the keyboard then it works in the obvious way.

Now here is the relevant Java code:

```
public void start() throws IOException{
        /*
        Start the process. create buffered reader and writer
        */
        System.out.println("Java:: Starting Process...");

        oProcess = new ProcessBuilder("root","-b","-q","external/test_io.C").start();

        InputStream oIs = oProcess.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader oIsReader = new InputStreamReader(oIs);
        oBr = new BufferedReader(oIsReader);

        OutputStream oOs = oProcess.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter oOsWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(oOs);
        oBw = new BufferedWriter(oOsWriter);
    }

    public void communicate()throws IOException{
        //sends stuff to the process and reads the results...
        read_stuff();
        write_stuff("message from java. blah blah blah");
        read_stuff();
    }

    private void write_stuff(String sMessage)throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Java:: write stuff: "+sMessage);
        oBw.write(sMessage);
        oBw.write("\n");
        oBw.flush();
    }

    private void read_stuff()throws IOException{
        /*
        reads stuff from the external process. returns the last line recieved
        */
        System.out.println("Java:: read_stuff...");
        String sLine;

        //wait for it to be ready...
        long end=System.currentTimeMillis()+2000;
        while ((System.currentTimeMillis() < end)){
            if (oBr.ready())
                break;
        }
        if (!oBr.ready()){
            System.out.println("Java:: NOT READY :/");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Java:: READY!!!");
        while ((sLine = oBr.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Java:: ...got line: " + sLine);
        }
        return;
    }
```

Calling `start` then `communicate` yields the following output:

```
Java:: Starting Process...
Java:: read_stuff...
Java:: READY!!!
Java:: ...got line:    ------------------------------------------------------------
Java:: ...got line:   | Welcome to ROOT 6.02/05                http://root.cern.ch |
Java:: ...got line:   |                               (c) 1995-2014, The ROOT Team |
Java:: ...got line:   | Built for linuxx8664gcc                                    |
Java:: ...got line:   | From tag v6-02-05, 9 February 2015                         |
Java:: ...got line:   | Try '.help', '.demo', '.license', '.credits', '.quit'/'.q' |
Java:: ...got line:    ------------------------------------------------------------
Java:: ...got line: 
Java:: ...got line: 
Java:: ...got line: Processing external/test_io.C...
```

And then it blocks. Java doesn't even receive the line 'ROOT:: loop iteration'.

Any help or direction will be appreciated. All my googling and experimentation has come up blank.

EDIT

Changing the `cout` statements to look like: `cout << "stuff" << endl;` makes things a little better. My java program out put now looks like:

```
Java:: Starting Process...
Java:: read_stuff...
Java:: READY!!!
Java:: ...got line:    ------------------------------------------------------------
Java:: ...got line:   | Welcome to ROOT 6.02/05                http://root.cern.ch |
Java:: ...got line:   |                               (c) 1995-2014, The ROOT Team |
Java:: ...got line:   | Built for linuxx8664gcc                                    |
Java:: ...got line:   | From tag v6-02-05, 9 February 2015                         |
Java:: ...got line:   | Try '.help', '.demo', '.license', '.credits', '.quit'/'.q' |
Java:: ...got line:    ------------------------------------------------------------
Java:: ...got line: 
Java:: ...got line: 
Java:: ...got line: Processing external/test_io.C...
Java:: ...got line: ROOT:: loop iteration
```

Then blocks.

Removing the line `cin >> in_str;` from the ROOT code causes the Java to generate the following infinite stuff:

```
Java:: ...got line: ROOT:: loop iteration
Java:: ...got line: ROOT:: recieved string 
Java:: ...got line: ROOT:: loop iteration
...etc
```

So the problem is now `cin`...

Comment: Downvotes should be accompanied by comments. That way the community gets better (as opposed to irritated)

Comment: The C++ output statements are without newlines, which will not flush the lines. Also, the Java code has to feed the C++ read.

Comment: @laune: thanks, that solves half the problem. I'm not sure what you mean by "feed the C++ read" though. I've detailed my changes and their results in an edit above.

Comment: You never execute `System.out.println("Java:: write stuff: "+sMessage);` and so the `cin >> in_str;` blocks. The Java program blocks in `while ((sLine = oBr.readLine()) != null) {` because this is a blocking read. `null` indicates EOF, which isn't here yet. - You are trying to implement a protocol where one side can send an arbitrary number of lines, but you still want to execute reads and writes synchronously in the Java program. Sending a string "your turn" to let the other side know that a bunch of messages has been finished is one way out. Not sure what you really want to implement, though

Comment: @laune: thanks for the help. I'm all sorted out. I you feel like putting your comments in an answer then I'll mark it as correct, otherwise I'll post an answer myself. I don't mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ output statements are without newlines, which will not flush the lines.

```
cout << "ROOT:: loop iteration" << endl;  
cin >> in_str;
cout << "ROOT:: received string " << in_str << endl;
```

The other problem is that the cin never "sees" a line sent from the Java program. You never execute

```
System.out.println("Java:: write stuff: "+sMessage);
```

and so the

```
cin >> in_str;
```

blocks. The Java program blocks in

```
while ((sLine = oBr.readLine()) != null) { ... }
```

because this is a blocking read. null indicates EOF, which isn't here yet.

You are trying to implement a protocol where one side can send an arbitrary number of lines, but you still want to execute reads and writes synchronously in the Java program. Sending a string "your turn" to let the other side know that a bunch of messages has been finished is one way out. Not sure what you really want to implement, though